# Spring + angularjs2 + war

Tags: spring, maven, angular

I want to create web application with spring using maven and angularjs2 and want to create war file at the end to deploy.
When we install angularjs2 and angular-material2, node_modules itself takes 175mb. Due to which war file will get heavy. Is there a way to minimize its size or to skip files which are not required. I thought of keeping only js files and removing all ts files from node_modules but in each folder of angularjs, there are more than one js file. One file is common in all folder which is index.js and this file also depends on many other files. Now I'm not getting which all js files to keep and which all are need to remove. Is there any tool or script available which can do this for me? 
Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: I think that `node_modules` files are for development time only. They are not required to run the final application.

Comment: Yes. But some of the files should be available in application otherwise browser will not get any files related to angularjs and page will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure maven war plugin to exclude node directory

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>node_modules/packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Also I would suggest to use grunt or any task manager to copy your important js file to another folder so that you can exclude the whole node_modules forlder.

Comment: As of now I'm using gulp. But I can change it to grunt. I'm having one question here. If I use grunt or gulp, will it take care of copying all required javascript files to required folder automatically or am i need to specify file names? If I need to specify file names, then how to find out what all files are required? Angular related js files are inside node_modules. If i skip node_modules how it application fill work?

Comment: You just need to specify the pattern of files and it will copy those files for you.

Comment: I use bower as package manager to manage my js files and use grunt-bowercopy task to copy the min.js file to my build directory and exclude other files. If this answer suits you please accept it.